# Joining data from different sources

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus

I'm currently trying to set up CPU-load alarming on grafana for my kubernetes cluster. For that I'd like to have a percental measure of the load (load of 3 on a 6 core CPU is 50%, load of 1 on a single core is 100%)

Unfortunately, as far as I can see there's no way to get these values directly from prometheus, but instead have to correlate the core count from kube-state-metrics with the actual load from prometheus-node-exporter.

My current attempt looks like the following:

```
node_load5 /
  on(kubernetes_node) 
  group_left(kubernetes_node)
kube_node_status_capacity_cpu_cores
```

But it fails with the following error:

```
parse error at char 60: label "kubernetes_node" must not occur in ON and GROUP clause at once
```

Comment: You can pull relevant metrics directly from cadvisor. Will this work for you? `sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id="/"}[1m])) / sum (machine_cpu_cores) * 100`

Comment: Also you can look into Prometheus Node_Exporter, which gets the host level matrices.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that I don't get alarming if one node is exhausted.

Comment: I couldn't find a metric with node cores in the node exporter.

Comment: with node exporter you can get number of cores with following rule `count(count(node_cpu) without (mode)) without (cpu)` Also check this example rules file - https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/pull/422